# Bootstrap scrollspy doesn't detect home

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently implemented my bootstrap nav with the scrollspy plugin.
I can notice 2 different problems:

- When I scroll to the top (in the home section) the scrollspy doesn't highlight "Home" in the bar.
- When I click between different sections sometimes the menu disappear for less then a second and then re-appear.

I've made a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8Gt7/4/

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="side-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link1">LINK 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link2">LINK 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link3">LINK 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="resume text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </div>
        </div>
        <section id="link1">
            <div class="row title_section text-center" style="background-color:#87c0e4;">LINK 1</div>
            <div class="mini_title text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
        </section>
        <section id="link2">
            <div class="row title_section text-center" style="background-color:#87c0e4;">LINK 2</div>
            <div class="mini_title text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
        </section>
        <section id="link3">
            <div class="row title_section text-center" style="background-color:#87c0e4;">LINK 3</div>
            <div class="mini_title text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    var myOffset = 50

    $("body").scrollspy({target: "#side-nav", offset:(myOffset+1)});

    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
        var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    })

    $('#link1').appear(function() {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    });
    $('#link2').appear(function() {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    });
    $('#link3').appear(function() {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    });

    $('.navbar-nav li a').click(function(){  
        $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').collapse('hide');
    });

    //SCROLL MENU
    function scrollNav() {
        $('.nav a').click(function(){  
        //Toggle Class
        $(".active").removeClass("active");   
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");

        if ($(this).attr('href') == "#home") {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 400);
        } else {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - myOffset}, 400);
        }
        return false;
    });
        $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
    }
    scrollNav();
    //END

});
```

**CSS**:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

#link1, #link2, #link3, #link4 {
    opacity: 0
}

.title_section {
  margin-top:150px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  color:white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight:400;
}


.mini_title {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified your id="home" anywhere in your code.
I think you should put like this

```
<div class="row" id="home">
        <div class="resume text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are absolutely right! And for the second problem? Maybe there's some conflict with the jQuery Appear script?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the 2nd problem on my Chrome browser, when I used the JSFiddle sample.

Comment: I'm using Safari 7.0.5

Comment: I think your below code is causing second issue.

'$('.navbar-nav li a').click(function(){  
     $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').collapse('hide');
});'


If you have kept it intentionally than we can do something with that or else you can remove it and it will solve your 2nd issue.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the collapse

Comment: I use it because when I'm in mobile view (with the toggle button) I want to collapse the menu after a click on a section. I'll try a workaround detecting with jQuery the presence of the toggle menu and applying the collapse code only in that situation! Thx